# Binding to DataGridColumnHeader.Command

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I need to use `Command` on `DataGridColumnHeader` to sort my data. Standard `DataGrid` sorting feature is not enough for me because there are not all data displayed in `DataGrid`. I don't even have all data present in my VM. (It's not possible... it's too much) I just request concrete page of data from server. And now I would also like to get concrete page from sorted data.

So I did this:

```xml
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entities, Mode=OneWay}" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntity}">
      <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
               <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"/>
               <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
           </Style>
      </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                     <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Column1" />
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Property1}"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

It works great. And now I just want to have `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` unfortunately it works no more. Is there anybody who can **explain** why it doesn't work for autogenerated columns and provide me with some solution? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

It has probably something to do with the fact that following doesn't work either.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entities, Mode=OneWay}" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntity}">
  <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
           <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"/>
           <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
       </Style>
  </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!-- HERE IS THE CHANGE -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>Column1</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Property1}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

But style is applied. I know this because I tried:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"/> <!-- beautiful tomato background -->
   <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"/>
   <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>
```

Column header has Tomato background, but command doesn't work.

**EDIT2**

Following is the solution. Apparently `DataGridColumnHeaders` doesn't inherit DataContext, because when I change the command binding everything works again.

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                Path=DataContext.MyCommand}"/>
```

But still I don't quite understand why. So answer with detailed explanation will get the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your findings suggest, autogenerated columns will have a DataGridColumn.Header with its DataContext set to the string header object.

If you do not use autogenerated columns, and instead specify a DataGridTemplateColumn and the DataGridTemplateColumn.Header, standard inheritance for the DataContext still applies, so that's why it worked for you the first time.

Edit: A quick search didn't provide immediate results where this behavior is described. However, verifying the fact is not too hard:

[image]

Xaml:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyClasses}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" MouseRightButtonUp="DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp_1" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Name (Manual Column)" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Class1> _myClasses;
    public ObservableCollection<Class1> MyClasses { get { return _myClasses; } set { _myClasses = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyClasses"); } }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyClasses = new ObservableCollection<Class1>()
        {
            new Class1() { Name = "Andy" },
            new Class1() { Name = "Mark" },
            new Class1() { Name = "Peter" },
            new Class1() { Name = "Gregor" },
            new Class1() { Name = "Jenny" }
        };
    }
}
```

Code behind (for illustration purpose only):

```cs
private void DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Microsoft.Windows.Themes.DataGridHeaderBorder)
    {
        object dataContext = ((Microsoft.Windows.Themes.DataGridHeaderBorder)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
    }
}
```

Right-click on the manual column header (outside the textblock) produces the following dataContext:

[image]

Right-click on the autogenerated column header:

[image]

Comment: I see... are you sure about your first statement(is string really datacontext there)? could you point me to some resources where I can verify this? and second time I also defined DatagridTemplateColumn, but I think I understand.

Comment: I added some illustration. In your first Edit, you set the complete header to an object of type string, instead of a DataGridColumnHeader object which in turn has a DataContext that can inherit the parent DataContext, I guess that's the reason this does not work.

Comment: I also suppose this is exactly what happens in autogenerated columns (Header="Name").

Answer (score 2):

[DataGridColumnHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheader.aspx) is container item for [DataGridColumn.Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.header.aspx) same as, for example, [ListBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx) is container item for each item in [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx)'s [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx).

Since ListBoxItem's DataContext will be set to an item from ListBox's ItemsSource, it is natural that DataGridColumnHeader's DataContext will be set to DataGridColumn.Header object.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought. But it doesn't
explain why it worked the first time.

Comment: This is also good answer so +1,  but adabyron put more energy in his answer. Thank you!